# What does this interview result mean?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

“Your CV is of great interest to us however, at present we have no opportunities which suit your profile. As such, we are keeping your CV on file and would like to keep in touch. We look forward to speaking to you again soon.”

I just want to know what would you understand this reply as? Does it mean I haven’t got the job?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a company telling me they don't have any suitable openings a rejection?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/104309/is-a-company-telling-me-they-dont-have-any-suitable-openings-a-rejection)

Answer (score 19):

You didn't get a job.

It's probably just a rejection and you shouldn't read too much into it. In the last years plenty of companies started to invest in "employer banding". They want candidates to be happy with the experience of applying for a job, because

- These candidates have friends and family. And the company doesn't want the candidate to tell friends and family they are unprofessional
- Glassdoor reviews, kununu, etc...
- Candidates develop their skills too. A person who may not be a great fit now, can be a great fit 2 years later or even for a different position that springs up in a few months.

This type of emails doesn't mean anything apart from: you didn't get the job.

Answer (score 4):

Yes your right you haven't got the job, but they may have a job in the future (this may just be a fiction to soften the blow)

Answer (score 4):

> Does it mean I haven’t got the job?

Yes. It means you don't have the job.

"We'll keep your resume/CV on file" is just a nice way of saying that.